# Dirac delta implies continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Given $p(x)y''(x)+q(x)y'(x)+r(x)y(x)=\delta(x),$ with $p\ne 0$ and $p,q,r$ continuous, why is it true that $y$ is continuous, but $y',y''$ may not be? Similarly, if $py''+qy'+ry=H,$ why must $y,y'$ be continuous, but $y''$ may be discontinuous?

Note that I am aware of various 'proofs' of this, but none that are fully rigorous.

Comment: A fully rigorous proof must be based on a fully rigorous definition of "solution" of such an ODE. What's yours?

Comment: @Woodface I don't have a rigorous one.